# Ethernet malfunction when booting with extra device on /dev

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, devices, ethernet

I have a customized Linux distro (created via buildroot) running on an embedded platform. The system consists in a processing module (Based on Samsung Exynos 4412 microprocessor) with a base board for peripherals (such as RS232, Ethernet, USB ports, etc). It connects to the Internet via Ethernet cable or Wi-Fi, and that is set during boot.

Recently, a module was added on the kernel to enable the connection of a new device, which appears as `/dev/ttyACM0`. Other peripherals have been used before, such as a serial printer (`/dev/ttyUSB0`) and no problems were observed.

On this case though, there's a strange behaviour. Nothing wrong happens when the system boots set to Wi-Fi, no matter the number of peripherals connected. Also, if it boots set to Ethernet and the `ttyACM0` device is connected afterwards, it functions normally. The problem happens when the system is booted set to Ethernet while the device is connected. On this case, shortly after a connection has been made (I'm able to access it and see that the device is listed on `/dev`) it loses the connection to the Internet.

Network interfaces don't have anything to do with `/dev`, right? They're listed elsewhere, not having any references in `/dev`. I don't see how one could possibly impact the other. Is there any reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Do you have more details of this embedded platform(a commecial name of this board like "Raspberry PI" or "Le Potato"...) ? This seems to be a kind of conflict like the ones you could have with PCI slots and IRQs, but maybe it is other protocol having this issue with addressing...

Comment: It's a FriendlyARM Tiny4412, a chinese board: http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny4412

Comment: And the connection you are trying to create with the `/dev/ttyACM0` is an Arduino shield? That kind of hardware is being connected to your SBC?

Comment: Sounds like your ethernet device is moving up and down as you connect other devices, i.e. from `enp2s0` it becomes `enp3s0` or `enp1s0`. Just copy `/etc/sysconfit/networkscripts/` files for your current device and name them after the new device, and edit device names inside. Or move back to `ethN` naming schema using kernel parameters or `udev` rules and your `eth0` will always be `eth0`.

Comment: @nwildner it's a relay module, connected via USB.

Comment: @ajeh that's a good point, I'll try to log the current network interfaces names in a .txt file over time. Even though I don't have the folder you mentioned in my `/etc`, probably because the kernel is customized...

Comment: If you don't have network scripts folder, your device may already be named following `ethN` convention. What's the output of `ifconfig` with and w/o an extra device attached?

Comment: You could use the `biosdevname=0` as a parameter of your bootloader to get back the `eth` and `wlan` name scheme... (don't know what bootloader you are using).

Comment: Can you somehow get at the console output to see what is going on? Is there a serial console? If not, can you use netconsole?